Issues adding new items to model's string array and displaying them
I have a property in a model that Is initially empty as string array (userReports) that will hold the users' notes. But when I attempt to append values to it and display it, it nothing updates. Racking my brain understanding data persistence overall so im not sure if im going about this the right way.
@Model
final class ActiveStash {
    var substanceClass: String
    var substance: String
    var weight: UInt
    var substanceCost: UInt?
    var StashDescription: String?
    var date: Date
    var unit: String
    var dosages: Int?
    var userReports: [String]?

    init(substanceClass: String, substance: String, weight: UInt, substanceCost: UInt? = nil, StashDescription: String? = nil, date: Date, unit: String, dosages: Int? = nil, userReports: [String]? = nil) {
        self.substanceClass = substanceClass
        self.substance = substance
        self.weight = weight
        self.substanceCost = substanceCost
        self.StashDescription = StashDescription
        self.date = date
        self.unit = unit
        self.dosages = dosages
        self.userReports = userReports
    }
}


Function to add the users' report to the model
   func addReport() {
        guard !inputReport.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        var updatedReports = stashed.userReports
        stashed.userReports = updatedReports

        updatedReports.append(inputReport)

        try? modelContext.save()

        dismiss()
    }

How I'm attempting to display the text after the function call from another page
struct StashLinkView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    let stashed: ActiveStash
    @State private var viewSelect = "Usage"
    var viewName = ["Usage", "Report"]
    let currencySymbol = Locale.current.currencySymbol ?? ""
    @State private var isSheetShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           /// other code
        }

   // not sure im im doing this block  correctly

        VStack {
            if let userReports = stashed.userReports, !userReports.isEmpty {
                ForEach(userReports, id: \.self) { report in
                    VStack {
                        Text(report) 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text("No Notes")
            }
        }


You are not updating the property, you are only updating a local variable that you then ignore. At least do stashed.userReports = updatedReports before calling save(). But why is the property optional to start with or why not set its default value to []?

Tried this and nada... and I set the property optional because it isnt required to be added to

How do you provide a value to stashed in your view? How do you update this value when you add a new report?

@Paulw11
what do you mean by provide a value to stashed? Im currently using a function to add a report and then attempting to use a loop to display it. see updated function

The view you have shown doesn't have a query for stashed, so presumably it is passed from the superview. How is the value obtained in the superview and provided to the view code you have shown?

func addReport() {
    guard !inputReport.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
     stashed.userReports.append(inputReport)

    try? modelContext.save()

    dismiss()
}

